# C# SendKeys has undeterministic results

Tags: c#, automation, sendkeys

We've built an automation system that uses `SendKeys`. We struggled for a long time with `sending ALT+X to a window` which was done by `"%x"`. It should have worked but it didn't, seemed like it has been sent separately even though this is the way the documentation states you should send a combination.

We solved it by adding brackets to the input string: `"%(x)"`. Is this a known issue?

No we have the same problem with `"%a"`, the solution with the brackets `("%(a)") didn't work`.
Please advise.

I found SendKeys.SendWait, it might solve it though we don't fully understand why we can't get deterministic results. Any ideas?

Comment: Using sendkeys with brackets so "^(a)" for example, simulates holding both keys down at the same time. Is this what you require? or one key at a time?

Comment: That syntax (brackets) is what MSDN says to use to send combinations (_to specify that any combination of SHIFT, CTRL, and ALT should be held down while several other keys are pressed..._). Hardly you can define SendKeys as _deterministic_. Your post keys with Windows messages and application will manage them when possible (maybe that's why SendWait works: you're waiting it processes each combination). Moreover SendKeys mechanism changed across versions.

Comment: Why don't you just use the automation API? Why did you choose input faking over the well-supported approach?

Comment: Because it looked easy to use of course.  It is not.  SendKeys was a VB6 mistake that Microsoft could not eliminate.